# Mention operating system in title

Tags: discussion, tags, title

Should mentioning the Operating System in titles be removed?

We have tags to indicate those information. And on *Stack Overflow* it is recommended to remove the language tag from the title.

Comment: Makes sense. I'd say this would be a good policy to implement.

Comment: That's a great suggestion

Comment: See my post below - there's a misconception that language tags should be *removed* on SO - they just needn't be added when they're NOT needed.  Titles should stand on their own.

Answer (score 10):

The operating system should be included in the title if it's an important requirement. It often is.

It is not recommended to remove the name of the language on Stack Overflow! I think you're confusing this with the recommendation not to include language names as “tags” in titles. That is:

- “How do I frobnicate a widget in C?” is a good title
- “C Frobnicate a widget” is a bad title

A title of the form
“*Application type with key characteristic on platform*” is perfectly reasonable for SR.SE.

Examples:

- [OS X window organization software with resizing shortcuts](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/296/os-x-window-organization-software)
  The fact that this is about OSX is absolutely critical, it's good to have it in the title, and it comes naturally.
- [Calendar application for Linux that plays well with Outlook and Exchange and works offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/98/calendar-application-for-linux-that-plays-well-with-outlook-and-exchange)
  The whole premise of this question is the use of Linux (under Windows, there is an obvious answer), so it's good to mention it explicitly in the title.
- [Draw freehand on Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/357/draw-freehand-on-android)
  Desktop operating systems tend to ship with some “paint” software. This question exists because Android doesn't, so mentioning Android in the title is better.

Counter-examples:

- [Tool for taking screenshot and quickly editing it](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/163/tool-for-taking-screenshot-and-quickly-editing-it)
  As the asker is looking for either a multi-platform tool or tools on common platforms, the platform is not a critical feature of this question. (The question itself is an answer of sorts for Linux.)
- [GUI app to create maps made up of polygons](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/151/what-software-should-i-use-for-creating-maps-made-up-of-polygons)
  As I write, the asker hasn't specified a platform. But even if he did, there's a good chance that answers would be cross-platform. So there's no need to mention the platform in the title.
- [What project planning software includes resource leveling and is cheaper than Microsoft Project?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-project-planning-software-includes-resource-leveling-and-is-cheaper-than-mi)
  The question doesn't even mention a platform. Presumably running a Linux or Windows application in a VM would be acceptable. So it's no wonder that the title doesn't mention a platform.

Comment: Shouldn't OS be a tag if it's a relevant limiter rather than be in the title?

Comment: @waxeagle It needs to be a tag, but that doesn't imply that it shouldn't be in the title. Not all titles need to specify the platform, but there's no call for systematically removing them.

Comment: I put the OS in the title if it is a very short title otherwise, and leave it out if the title is getting long.

Comment: To me, the third counter-example would clearly indicate OP is after software for Windows. Well, in that case it doesn't need to be mentioned either. Might be nice to mention in the full text, though, to be found with searches.

Comment: I think it is recommended not to have tags in titles. See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/158075).

Comment: @moose “Don't put tags in title” means not to write things like “windows - best text editor”. It doesn't mean not to put things in title if they're implied by the tags, which would be silly.

Answer (score 5):

### Titles should be complete summaries of the question.

Here's the easy rule:

**Cover the tags, and ask yourself if the title conveys enough information.  It needs to**.

That means two things:

- Information in a tag *in no way* makes it less necessary in a title.
- But tags need not be added to a title when they're *not* needed to convey key information

Tags are for filtering, not for completing otherwise incomplete titles.

[See this meta post for more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100/titles-should-be-stand-alone-summaries-of-questions-without-depending-on-tags?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Gilles in [Why do people insist titles actually be a question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68) (I seem to be unable to find a “share” link on the specific answer…) refers to a meta.SO FAQ with a scientifically-based highest-scored answer on titles.

The part interesting here is: Do not copy parts of the question in the title.

Comment: I personally think that it should probably be repeated __if__ it’s an _important_ requirement (it is a requirement in most cases, but we got tags anyway…). But I thought I should add this answer here nevertheless, in case someone thinks differently.